# How do I prevent ag-grid's floating filter from showing auto-complete?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I'm trying ag-grid's new prop for column configuration, as documented on this page:

https://ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/floating-filters/#controlling-autocomplete-on-floating-filters

It's supposed to hide Chrome's (or any other browser's) autocomplete from appearing in the floating filter component for the column.
I'm using their official example, from this page:
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/component-floating-filter/

This is how my code and the output look side by side:
[image: plunker image]

What am I doing wrong?